# DigitalOcean ip address of a website doesn’t respond on ipads/iphones

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

i have a node/express with bulma css website droplet on digitalocean 5$/m and it works well by its ip ( no domain yet ) for android and desktop, while not resonding on iphone and ipad ( safari and chrome) , i tested it many versions and devices, knowing that there’s no SSL .
the browser said ( safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding).
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a domain and SSL will solve this issue .